# Can't set the damage value(s) to insta-kill NPCs/Players in a Garry's Mod "Spartan Kick" addon

Tags: lua, steam, garrys-mod

This is a uh usual change of what I post here on StackOverflow! Today I'm trying to edit someone's Garry's Mod Workshop Addon.

I wanted to make it a one-hit kill and it's a Spartan Kick.

Here is the code:

```lua
if( SERVER ) then
    AddCSLuaFile( "shared.lua" );
end

if( CLIENT ) then
    SWEP.Category = "Epic Kicks";
    SWEP.PrintName = "Spartan Kick";
    SWEP.WepSelectIcon = surface.GetTextureID("VGUI/entities/spartan_kick") 
    SWEP.Slot = 1;
    SWEP.SlotPos = 4;
    SWEP.DrawAmmo = false;
    SWEP.DrawCrosshair = false;
end

SWEP.Author         = "Shot846 (Original) + 2Epic4You (Modified)"
SWEP.Instructions   = "A better Sparta Kick. Use sv_cheats 1 for slow-motion!"
SWEP.Contact        = "..."
SWEP.Purpose        = "THIS IS EDITED SPARTAAAAAAA!"

SWEP.ViewModelFOV   = 75
SWEP.ViewModelFlip  = false

SWEP.Spawnable          = true
SWEP.AdminSpawnable     = true

SWEP.NextStrike = 0;
  
SWEP.ViewModel      = "models/weapons/v_kick.mdl"
SWEP.WorldModel   = ""
  
-------------Primary Fire Attributes----------------------------------------
SWEP.Primary.Delay          = 0.4   --In seconds
SWEP.Primary.Recoil         = 0     --Gun Kick
SWEP.Primary.Damage         = math.huge --Damage per Bullet
SWEP.Primary.NumShots       = 1     --Number of shots per one fire
SWEP.Primary.Cone           = 0     --Bullet Spread
SWEP.Primary.ClipSize       = -1    --Use "-1 if there are no clips"
SWEP.Primary.DefaultClip    = -1    --Number of shots in next clip
SWEP.Primary.Automatic      = true  --Pistol fire (false) or SMG fire (true)
SWEP.Primary.Ammo           = "none"    --Ammo Type

-------------Secondary Fire Attributes----------------------------------------
SWEP.Secondary.Delay            = 0     --In seconds
SWEP.Secondary.Recoil           = 0     --Gun Kick
SWEP.Secondary.Damage           = math.huge --Damage per Bullet
SWEP.Secondary.NumShots     = 1     --Number of shots per one fire
SWEP.Secondary.Cone         = 0     --Bullet Spread
SWEP.Secondary.ClipSize     = -1    --Use "-1 if there are no clips"
SWEP.Secondary.DefaultClip  = -1    --Number of shots in next clip
SWEP.Secondary.Automatic    = true  --Pistol fire (false) or SMG fire (true)
SWEP.Secondary.Ammo             = "none"    --Ammo Type
 
-------------Precache Sounds----------------------------------------
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/madness.mp3")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/foot_kickwall.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/foot_kickbody.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/sparta.mp3")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick1.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick2.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick3.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick4.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick5.wav")
util.PrecacheSound("player/skick/kick6.wav")

function SWEP:Initialize()
    if( SERVER ) then
            self:SetWeaponHoldType("normal");
    end
    self.Hit = { 
    Sound( "player/skick/foot_kickwall.wav" )};
    self.FleshHit = {
    Sound( "player/skick/kick1.wav" ),
    Sound( "player/skick/kick2.wav" ),
    Sound( "player/skick/kick3.wav" ),
    Sound( "player/skick/kick4.wav" ),
    Sound( "player/skick/kick5.wav" ),
    Sound( "player/skick/kick6.wav" ) } ;

end

function SWEP:Precache()
end

function SWEP:Deploy()
    self.Weapon:SendWeaponAnim( ACT_VM_IDLE );
    return true;
end

function SWEP:PrimaryAttack()
     if( CurTime() < self.NextStrike ) then return; end
     self.Weapon:EmitSound("player/skick/sparta.mp3")
     self.NextStrike = ( CurTime() + 3.5 );
     timer.Simple( 1.80, function() self.AttackAnim(self) end)
     timer.Simple( 2.40, function() self.Weapon:SendWeaponAnim( ACT_VM_IDLE ) end)
     timer.Simple( 2.0,  function() self.ShootBullets (self) end)
     self.Owner:SetAnimation( PLAYER_ATTACK1 );
end 

function SWEP:ShootBullets()
    self.Weapon:EmitSound("player/skick/foot_swing.wav");
    local trace = self.Owner:GetEyeTrace();
    if trace.HitPos:Distance(self.Owner:GetShootPos()) <= 130 then
        if( trace.Entity:IsPlayer() or trace.Entity:IsNPC() or trace.Entity:GetClass()=="prop_ragdoll" ) then
                timer.Simple(0, function() game.ConsoleCommand("host_timescale 0.1\n") end) 
                timer.Simple(0.1, function() game.ConsoleCommand("host_timescale 1\n") end)
            self.Owner:EmitSound( self.FleshHit[math.random(1,#self.FleshHit)] );
        else
            self.Owner:EmitSound( self.Hit[math.random(1,#self.Hit)] );
        end
                bullet = {}
                bullet.Num    = 5
                bullet.Src    = self.Owner:GetShootPos()
                bullet.Dir    = self.Owner:GetAimVector()
                bullet.Spread = Vector(0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
                bullet.Tracer = 0
                bullet.Force  = math.huge
                bullet.Damage = math.huge
            self.Owner:FireBullets(bullet)
    end
    
    if trace.Entity:GetClass() == "prop_door_rotating" then
     trace.Entity:EmitSound(Sound("physics/wood/wood_box_impact_hard3.wav"))
     trace.Entity:Fire("open", "", .001)
     trace.Entity:Fire("unlock", "", .001)
     local pos = trace.Entity:GetPos()
     local ang = trace.Entity:GetAngles()
     local model = trace.Entity:GetModel()
     local skin = trace.Entity:GetSkin()
     trace.Entity:SetNotSolid(true)
     trace.Entity:SetNoDraw(true)
     local function ResetDoor(door, fakedoor)
     door:SetNotSolid(false)
     door:SetNoDraw(false)
     fakedoor:Remove()
     end
     local norm = (pos - self.Owner:GetPos()):Normalize()
     local push = 1000000 * norm
     local ent = ents.Create("prop_physics")
     ent:SetPos(pos)
     ent:SetAngles(ang)
     ent:SetModel(model)
    if(skin) then
      ent:SetSkin(skin)
    end
     ent:Spawn()
     timer.Simple(.01, ent.SetVelocity, ent, push)               
     timer.Simple(.01, ent:GetPhysicsObject().ApplyForceCenter, ent:GetPhysicsObject(), push)
     timer.Simple(140, ResetDoor, trace.Entity, ent)
end

end

function SWEP:SecondaryAttack()
     if( CurTime() < self.NextStrike ) then return; end
     self.NextStrike = ( CurTime() + 0.75 );
     timer.Simple( 0.00, function() self.AttackAnim(self) end)
     timer.Simple( 0.75, function() self.Weapon:SendWeaponAnim( ACT_VM_IDLE ) end)
     timer.Simple( 0.20,  function() self.ShootBullets (self) end)
     self.Owner:SetAnimation( PLAYER_ATTACK1 );
end 

function SWEP:Reload()
     if( CurTime() < self.NextStrike ) then return; end
     self.Weapon:EmitSound("player/skick/madness.mp3")
     self.NextStrike = ( CurTime() + 2.00 );
end

function SWEP:AttackAnim()
    self.Weapon:SendWeaponAnim( ACT_VM_PRIMARYATTACK )
end
```

Yes it works however it isn't instantly killing the NPC I spawn.

What value do I need to change to make it insta-kill?

## **What I've tried:**

- Changing all damage values found to math.huge

## **What I've found:**

- I have found that it does still damage the NPC and the original value was `1000000` however it didn't insta-kill the NPC.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually figured it out! After some extensive researching on the Wiki, I found out you can have bullet.Callback and so this is what I did:

```
                bullet = {}
                bullet.Num    = 10
                bullet.Src    = self.Owner:GetShootPos()
                bullet.Dir    = self.Owner:GetAimVector()
                bullet.Spread = Vector(0.04, 0.04, 0.04)
                bullet.Tracer = 0
                bullet.Force  = 20000
                bullet.Damage = 999999
                bullet.Callback = function(attacker, tree, damageinfo)
                    if(trace.Entity:IsNPC()) then
                        trace.Entity:SetHealth(0) 
                    elseif(trace.Entity:IsPlayer()) then
                        trace.Entity:Kill()
                    end
                end
            self.Owner:FireBullets(bullet)
```